# Format the current date in java

Tags: java

I want format the current date to a format, I can do that in the following lines

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd:HH:mm:ss");
Date currentDate = new Date();
String currentDateString = dateFormat.format(currentDate);
try {
    currentDate = dateFormat.parse(currentDateString);
} catch (ParseException e) {

}
```

But is there a way more clear and tidy to achieve that ?

Comment: But what does this code do? You are converting a Date object to String and back to Date object. So finally you are having the same object.

Comment: @Dinal, no, even ignoring the loss of the fraction on the second, you're not guaranteed to get the same date-time back when the current date-time falls during a daylight-savings-time transition in the default locale since there may be two date-times that correspond to a particular formatted date string.

Comment: @MikeSamuel, I agree that there can be a difference of upto 1 or 2 seconds. When I said same object, I didnt mean .equals(). But I couldn't find any use of the above code. If he was using it for any display purpose, he could have used the converted String.

Comment: @Dinal, There can be a difference of up to 1 hour and 1 second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Java 8 and the new classes [`LocalDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) and [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to format to a `String`. Don't use `Date` from Java 7 and lower. That old API is a mess.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now();
System.out.println(ldt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd:HH:mm:ss")));
```

Output:

```
2014-06-08:14:43:01
```

Comment: That's not the same format that the OP wanted though now is it? You haven't really reduced the number of lines of code - just inlined some lines.

Comment: Changed the format. And, no, it is not "just inlining" but using the Java 8 API. Since the OP asked for "clear" and "tidy", that's what I propose.

Comment: I'm all for Java 8! I think we need to work out what the OP actually wants though - the question is formatting a `Date` to a `String` then parsing back to a `Date`. This answer is not equivalent.

Comment: One might mention, that the new java 8 date/time handling and the several new classes are a major improvement (clarity).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to migrate to Java 8. If use java 6 or 7, I can use [Joda-Time library](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/index.html). 
JSR-310 form Java 8 is started from scratch, but with an API 'inspired by Joda-Time'.

Here you have example:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd:HH:mm:ss");
String str = date.toString(fmt);
// might output "6 October, 2013"
```